# Coverflowjs and Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, coverflow

Using [coverflowjs](http://coverflowjs.github.io/coverflow/) and [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) together doesn't seem to work out of the box.

I'm trying to implement [coverflowjs](http://coverflowjs.github.io/coverflow/) on a div that is wrapped by a knockout [`with` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html).

I have setup a jsfiddle to do some testing. Expected functionality: 
When the button is pressed, the coverflow with the placehold.it images should show in a coverflow way as the one that's hooked up with the coverflow-noknockout css class.

http://jsfiddle.net/bz8sczqr/21/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/gqLd381z/2/. The required change is:

```
self.displayCoverflow.subscribe(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".coverflow").coverflow();
    }, 0);
});
```

The "with" binding is tricky as it add its contents to the DOM only when the condition becomes true. To make Coverflowjs happy you need to use `setTimeout(.., 0)` which allows everything to settle down before it kicks in.